# How to draw the very basic people using TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using [`tikzpeople`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpeople) I can draw following figure (*Bob*) (`\node[bob,minimum size=0.8cm, label=\scriptsize Bob] (ail)`), with the help of following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338436/127048):

[image]

---

I was wondering is it possible to draw much basic version of it as follows (text could be on top):

[image]

Please note that figure is take from following [publication](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/f9/91/f5/ea10af2f6e8462/US20190095879A1.pdf).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84275/238301

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377331/customising-the-person-symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually see no reason to do it with tikzpeople if you can do it easily in tikz alone with just a view commands.

```
\documentclass[border=3.5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle [radius=18pt] node[yshift=10mm] {Alice};
        \draw[thick,fill=black] (1,-1.8) arc(0:180:1cm and 1 cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

But by loading draft you can draw tikzpeople in their basic shape. But is not really meant to work with, but to compile huge pictures faster.

```
\documentclass[border=3.5mm]{standalone}


\usepackage[draft]{tikzpeople}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[bob,minimum size=1.5cm] {Bob};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had trouble make drawn people align and scale, please see the related question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/591410/127048)