# How to scale and align the very basic people using TiKZ on top of a time-line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My question is related to [following answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590743/127048) in order to draw very basic(draft) people. I am having trouble to align and scale basic people on top of a time-line. Following code piece draws little bit large peope figures.

> ````
> \usepackage{tikz}
>
> \begin{document}
>     
>     \begin{tikzpicture}
>         \draw[fill=black] (0,0) circle [radius=18pt] node[yshift=10mm] {Alice};
>         \draw[thick,fill=black] (1,-1.8) arc(0:180:1cm and 1 cm);
>     \end{tikzpicture}
>      \end{document} ```
> ````

---

Example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (11,0) node (b)[below] {} ;
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,50,...,500}
  {
    \def \inBetSpace {1}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*\inBetSpace-\inBetSpace,-2mm) node[below](n\i) {\x} -- ++(0,4mm);
  }
  \node[bob,minimum size=0.8cm, label=\scriptsize Bob] (ail) at (2,2.4) {};
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (ail) -- +(0,-2.4+0.2)node[fill=white, anchor=center, double=black,
midway,inner sep=1pt](a){\tiny Submits};

    \node[bob,minimum size=0.8cm, label=\scriptsize Alice] (ail) at (5,2.4) {};
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (ail) -- +(0,-2.4+0.2)node[fill=white, anchor=center, double=black,
midway,inner sep=1pt](a){\tiny Submits};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

I just want to replace `Alice` and `Bob` with the basic people figure.

- I was not able to make it align and scale.
- I was not able to link arrows linked to the drawn people figure.

Is there any easy way to draw following sketch?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (0,0)node(a){} -- (11,0) node (b)[below] {} ;
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0,50,...,500}
  {
    \def \inBetSpace {1}
    \draw[line width=1pt] (\i*\inBetSpace-\inBetSpace,-2mm) node[below](n\i) {\x} -- ++(0,4mm);
  }

    % Bob
  \draw[thick,fill=black] (2.4,2.2) arc(0:180:0.4cm and 0.4 cm) node[below,midway](ail){Bob};
  \node[above=of ail,circle,fill=black,yshift=-0.9cm,minimum size=0.5cm,label=above:{\scriptsize Bob}]{};
  
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (ail) -- +(0,-2.2+0.2)node[fill=white, anchor=center, double=black,
midway,inner sep=1pt](a){\tiny Submits};


    % Alice
  \draw[thick,fill=black] (5.4,2.2) arc(0:180:0.4cm and 0.4 cm) node[below,midway](ail){alice};
  \node[above=of ail,circle,fill=black,yshift=-0.9cm,minimum size=0.5cm,label=above:{\scriptsize Alice}]{};
  
  \draw[->, -Latex, line width=1pt] (ail) -- +(0,-2.2+0.2)node[fill=white, anchor=center, double=black,
midway,inner sep=1pt](a){\tiny Submits};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: added `\scriptsize` to change font size for Bob and Alice.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how does it work but thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. In onder to change font size for Bob and Alice should I use `\scriptsize` before them?

Comment: To adjust font size in a node you can do it like normal in LaTex with `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge` and `\Huge`.