# Adjusting colors and thickness of stick figure

Tags: color, tikzsymbols

I'm using the `tikzsymbols` package (documented here: https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzsymbols/tikzsymbols.pdf).

So far I've been able to create a stick figure, scale it and adjust the arms and feet.

What I can't seem to work out is how to adjust the thickness of the lines and the line color.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Strichmaxerl[10][45][16][89][35]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't seem that `\Strichmaxerl` supports changing the color or thickness. Is there some other way to do it?

The above gives me a very thick figure (in black color):

[image]

The end goal is to have the head and body in different colors (yellow and blue), but for starters, at least changing the overall color would be ideal.

Comment: Color is straightforward: `\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[blue] {\Strichmaxerl[20][45][16][89][35]};
\end{tikzpicture}`. First parameter is the overall scale.  However, there does not appear to be a way to adjust the line thickness relative to the scale. See https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzsymbols/tikzsymbols.pdf

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377331/customising-the-person-symbol

Comment: Thanks @steven. I ended up going for a simpler approach of just using plain `tikz`, which gives great flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using pure `tikz` due to limitations with the other package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% head
\draw[blue, very thick] (0,0.4) circle (0.4);

% body
\draw[red, very thick] (0,0) -- (0,-0.8);

% arms
\draw[red, very thick] (0,-0.5) -- (250:1cm);
\draw[red, very thick] (0,-0.5) -- (-20:0.6cm);

% feet
\draw[red, very thick] (0,-0.8) -- (305:1.3cm);
\draw[red, very thick] (0,-0.8) -- (280:1.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

You have better control over the color and thickness with `\draw`.

Ironically, "very thick" worked best in this case!

Great intro here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package

[image]